# GIT Hook Doubts

Tags: php, git, shell

```
git diff --cached --name-only | while read FILE; do
if [[ "$FILE" =~ ^.+(php|inc)$ ]]; then
    if [[ -f $FILE ]]; then
        php -l "$FILE" 1> /dev/null
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
           scopeVar=1;
            echo -e "\e[1;31m\tAborting commit due to files with syntax errors. $FILE \e[0m" >&2
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
fi
done || exit $?
```

I have written code in pre-commit that will check if there are no syntax error. But have some doubt

1. It will check syntax error based on PHP version of the developer (which nay vary) and I believe it should be based on server PHP version. how to handle this
2. Scope of   variables "scopeVar" ends in while loop only and suppose I want to perform something outside while loop based on value of scopeVar.
   Can i handle this

Comment: If you're using bash, you can use process substitution instead of a pipe to avoid this problem: `done <(git diff --cached --name-only)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is a workaround](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) for the scope problem in Bash:

```
declare myvar

git diff --cached --name-only |
{
  while IFS= read -r FILE; do
    # your code...
    myvar=1
  done

  echo $myvar # outputs 1
}
```

Regarding the PHP version. I would do this on the client side with a PHP version check, e.g.

```
fatal_error()
{
  echo >&2 "$1"
  exit 1
}

test_php_ver()
{
  r=`php -r 'echo version_compare(PHP_VERSION, "5.6.19") >= 0 ? 1 : 0;'`
  [ $r -eq 1 ] || fatal_error "Invalid php version"
}

test_php_ver
```